# Riak node terminated with I/0 error

Tags: ubuntu, riak, leveldb, riak-cs

My riak nodes are terminating unexpectedly with the following error. This thing started to happen after i made the following change. That's the only change i did.

{riak_kv, [ {storage_backend, riak_kv_eleveldb_backend},

Error in crash.log

2013-11-17 08:51:54 =SUPERVISOR REPORT====
     Supervisor: {local,riak_core_sup}
     Context:    child_terminated
     Reason:     {{function_clause,[{riak_kv_vnode,terminate,[{bad_return_value,{stop,{db_open,"IO error: ./data/leveldb/45671926166590716193865151022383844364247891968/MANIFEST-000002: Cannot allocate memory"}}},undefined],[{file,"src/riak_kv_vnode.erl"},{line,838}]},{riak_core_vnode,terminate,3,[{file,"src/riak_core_vnode.erl"},{line,849}]},{gen_fsm,terminate,7,[{file,"gen_fsm.erl"},{line,586}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,227}]}]},{gen_fsm,sync_send_event,[<0.2083.0>,wait_for_init,infinity]}}
     Offender:   [{pid,<0.161.0>},{name,riak_core_vnode_manager},{mfargs,{riak_core_vnode_manager,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,5000},{child_type,worker}]

I started my riak nodes with the sudo access and nodes working properly after i started. Then after a couple of seconds nodes are terminating unexpectedly with the above error.

Any suggestions to solve this problem will be a great help.
Thank You.

Comment: This doesn't look like programming. It might fit better over at ServerFault or some other site. Even then, though, it's pretty poorly written. Where did you make this change? What did you change it from?

Comment: I changed it from bit bucket to level db, in riak/etc/app.config. And i think it's the only place that you can change the backend of riak. So i think anybody should know that, who works with riak and that's why i didn't mentioned that. Sorry for my poor English. thanks..

Comment: This question has answered in here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325311/riak-database-fails-after-a-short-period?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by maamaa above a solution is on the question [Riak database fails after a short period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325311/riak-database-fails-after-a-short-period?rq=1).

In short

```
disable AAE by setting {anti_entropy, {off, []}}
```

in the riak config (etc/app.config)